# 'ne' is not working in do-while loop, whereas '!=' works

Tags: perl, do-while

I'm not sure what mistake I'm making, but I just changed `ne` to `!=` and it worked.

This is a simple program to let the user guess a number until they hit a target number.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $guess = 1;

do {
    $guess = <STDIN>;
} while ( $guess != 12 ) ; # it doesn't work if i replace != with ne

say "you guessed ", $guess;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [how to ask]. Your first question was well-written and well-received. Now that you have a good answer that obviously helped you, the next step is to mark it as _accepted_ so visitors can later see that it solved the problem.

Answer (score 14):

Perl's `ne` is the  *string* not-equal operator, so `$guess` and `12` are treated as strings.

A string obtained via `<>` contains a newline character at the end, so it is not equal to the string `'12'`.

`!=` is the *numeric* not-equal operator, so both operands are treated as numbers. In this case Perl will ignore any trailing non-numeric characters when making the conversion, so the newline is ignored and the string `12<newline>` is treated as numeric `12`.

Were you to `chomp` the obtained value before comparison, the `ne` operator would also work.

Comment: Since this involves user input it may be good to mention possible trailing spaces as well.